# finding all substrings of a very large string in python

Tags: python

I am trying to find all substring of a string. It works great with smaller length size strings but when length of string is increased such as 5000, it gives memory error. Is there any way to find substring of long string?

```
S="sample string"
all=[]

for i in range(0,len(S)):
    for j in range(0,len(S)):
        if len(S[i:j])>0 and S[i:j] not in all:
            all.append(S[i:j])
        if len(S[-i:])>0 and S[-i:] not in all:
            all.append(S[-i:])
```

Comment: If you don't have the option of processing that substring immediately, but you need the substrings as such consider using a database. Due to plain combinatorics the output is going to be huge.

Comment: Try using the ```itertools.combinations(iterable, r) ``` - with r step till you reach the length of the string in a lopp or so ... https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations , for memory issues try persisting the results to a file, db etc...

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import combinations
    
S = "sample string"  
print([''.join(l) for i in range(len(S)) for l in combinations(S, i+1)])
```

Comment: Another way of producing that really huge list will not solve the problem. At least an iterator instead of a list comprehension should be considered.

Answer (score 0):

If you can adapt to having duplicates, you can use a generator:

```
s="sample string"
sub_strings_dups_inc=(s[i: j] for i in range(len(s)) for j in range(i + 1, len(s) + 1))
```

That will generate each sub string one at a time (without having your more complicated filtering of if the string length is 0, etc)

If you need to filter out all duplicates, you will need to have the entire combination set in memory at the end of the string and will be limited by that. You could do:

```
def sub_strings(s):
    seen=set()
    for i in range(len(s)):
        for j in range(i+1, len(s)+1):
            ss=s[i:j]
            if ss not in seen:
                seen.add(ss)
                yield ss
```

---

(btw: Don't use `all` as a variable as habit. You will overwrite the built-in function by the same name...)

Answer (score 0):

Can give a try to subslices function in more-itertools:

https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#more_itertools.subslices

https://pypi.org/project/more-itertools/

OR Can try this:

```
from itertools import combinations, starmap, repeat
import operator

seq = "sample"  
slices = starmap(slice, combinations(range(len(seq) + 1), 2))
print(list(map(operator.getitem, repeat(seq), slices)))

['s', 'sa', 'sam', 'samp', 'sampl', 'sample', 'a', 'am', 'amp', 'ampl', 'ample', 'm', 'mp', 'mpl', 'mple', 'p', 'pl', 'ple', 'l', 'le', 'e']
```